# Run python script with elevated privileges installed with setuptools

Tags: python, pip, setuptools, sudo

I wrote a module that needs elevated privileges.

This is an excerpt from my **setup.py**:

```
...

entry_points={
    "console_scripts": [
        "wlan-monitor = wlan_monitor.wlan_monitor:main"
    ],
}

...
```

Installed with `pip3 install .` the `wlan-monitor` command is only available for the current user. `sudo wlan-monitor` is not available.

Since installing modules with sudo is discouraged, I'm searching for an alternative, where I can install the module as normal user but start the program with elevated privileges.

Comment: "*discouraged*" doesn't mean forbidden. In your case `sudo pip install` is most probably the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

If you could install a module as a normal user but start the program with elevated privileges, then that would be a technique that ordinary users could use to compromise system security.

@phd notes that you can just use the `sudo pip install`. That's fine.

Another approach would be to use your operating systems' proprietary privilege escalation approach. For example, [MacOS has an approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1371092/running-script-with-admin-permissions-on-os-x), and [Windows has another](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/91df08f3-30d7-4be5-aba9-89a6f3902cba/executing-a-script-with-elevated-privileges?forum=winserverpowershell).